# findviewbyid is giving null

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-relativelayout

I am having an activity and a layout for it .I have included a view in this layout which is common in all activities for showing error message.This common view is working fine  in all of the activities but in one activity findviewby id is giving null for this view.Have tried a lot but not able to track where the problem is.Please see the code if anyone can suggest me something.Here is the code

**Activity:**

```
public class VerificationCodeActivity extends Activity {

    TextView resend_code,other_numbers;
    EditText vc_code1,vc_code2,vc_code3,vc_code4;
    Button verify_code;
    RelativeLayout error_layout;
    TextView error_textview;
    Button close_error_button;
    Context ctx =this;
    String confirmCode;
    Bundle bundle;
    String usernumber,countrycode,tempid;
    ArrayList<String>other_numebr_list;
    String accessType;


        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    setContentView(R.layout.verification_code_layout);
    init();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
    void init()
    {
        resend_code = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.vc_resend_button);
        resend_code.setPaintFlags(resend_code.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
        error_textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.error_text);

        //here is the layout
        error_layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.error_layout);
        close_error_button= (Button)findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        }
    }
    void showErrorMessage(Boolean showm,String message )
    {

        if(showm)
        {
            error_textview.setText(message);
            CommonUtility.expand(error_layout);
        }
        else{
            CommonUtility.collapse(error_layout);
        }
    }
```

class VerifyCode extends AsyncTask
{

```
String response;
Boolean askpin,iserror = false;
String verifiedBy = "2";

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(iserror)
    {
        showErrorMessage(true, response);
    }
    else if(askpin)
    {
        Intent startcreatpin = new Intent(ctx, CreatePasswordActivity.class);
        startcreatpin.putExtra(VariableClass.Vari.VERIFI_CODE,confirmCode);
        startcreatpin.putExtra(VariableClass.Vari.USERID,bundle.getString(VariableClass.Vari.COUNTRYCODE)+bundle.getString(VariableClass.Vari.USERID));
        ctx.startActivity(startcreatpin);
    }
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    JSONObject parent,child;

    response = Apis.getApisInstance(ctx).verifyCode(bundle.getString(VariableClass.Vari.USERID), bundle.getString(VariableClass.Vari.COUNTRYCODE), Prefs.getResellerID(ctx), confirmCode, "2");

    if(!response.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        try {
            parent=new JSONObject(response);
            //if response of failed show message
            if(parent.getString(VariableClass.ResponseVariables.RESPONSE).equals(Apis.ErrorResponse))
            { 
                iserror = true;
                child= parent.getJSONObject(VariableClass.ResponseVariables.RESPONSEMESSAGE);
                response= child.getString(VariableClass.ResponseVariables.ERRORMESSAGE);
            }
            //if response of success send to create pin
            if(parent.getString(VariableClass.ResponseVariables.RESPONSE).equals(Apis.SuccessResponse))
            { 
                //hit verifiedsignup

                if(!tempid.equals(""))
                {
                    response = Apis.getApisInstance(ctx).verifiedsignup(verifiedBy, Prefs.getResellerID(ctx), bundle.getString(VariableClass.Vari.TEMP_ID),Prefs.getUserTariff(ctx));
                    if(!response.equals("")){
                        askpin= true;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        iserror = true;
                        response= getResources().getString(R.string.server_error);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            iserror=true;
            response=getResources().getString(R.string.parse_error);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        iserror=true;
        response=getResources().getString(R.string.server_error);
    }

    return null;
}
```

}
}

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_all" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vc_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:text="@string/vc_message"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/vc__em_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            layout="@layout/error_message_layout"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vc_code_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_box_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_shape_layout" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vc_code1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_shape_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="X"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/partition_line_width"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vc_code2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_shape_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="X"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/partition_line_width"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vc_code3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_shape_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="X"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="@dimen/partition_line_width"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/vc_code4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_shape_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="X"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:maxLength="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edit_text_size" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/options"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vc_othernumber_option"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="@string/other_number"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vc_resend_button"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:padding="1dp"
                android:text="@string/resend"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/vc_verifycode_button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/button_height"
            android:layout_below="@id/options"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
            android:text="@string/verify_text"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/button_text_size" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/logo_s" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Layout Included:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/error_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/curve_corner_shape_errormsg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_bottom_em"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/padding_left_em"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/padding_right_em"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top_em" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/right_padding_em"
        android:text="Invalid userName"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_em" />

    <Button

        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/close_button_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/close_button_height"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/close_button_margin_top"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Method**
//priting true
public static void expand(final View v) {

```
Boolean b=false;
if(v==null)
{
    b=true;
}
Log.e("check if view is null",""+b);
v.measure(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
final int targtetHeight = v.getMeasuredHeight();

v.getLayoutParams().height = 0;
v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Animation a = new Animation()
{
    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                ? LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        : (int)(targtetHeight * interpolatedTime);
        v.requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean willChangeBounds() {
        return true;
    }
};

// 1dp/ms
a.setDuration((int)(targtetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
v.startAnimation(a);
```

}

**Log:**

```
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at commonUtilities.CommonUtility.expand(CommonUtility.java:86)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.phone91new.VerificationCodeActivity.showErrorMessage(VerificationCodeActivity.java:244)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.phone91new.VerificationCodeActivity$VerifyCode.onPostExecute(VerificationCodeActivity.java:264)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.phone91new.VerificationCodeActivity$VerifyCode.onPostExecute(VerificationCodeActivity.java:1)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-07 17:44:04.430: E/AndroidRuntime(22640):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
```

Comment: Don't you think this is wrong. ??`setContentView(R.layout.verification_code_layout);
        init();
        super.onCreate(arg0);` Need to exchange them

Comment: What is at line no 244 of VerificationCodeActivity ?

Comment: @X'Factor hi,have changed that but still same error is coming

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha The error is here `CommonUtility.expand(error_layout);`. so need to show that method.

Comment: @X'Factor have updated the question

Comment: I think you have included layout which has a id `vc__em_layout` and for Relative Layout its id is `error_layout`. So thats y you are getting NPE exception.

Comment: @X'Factor have have included error_layout only and has given id to this as vc_em_layout.

Comment: Try to use View and give a id of vc__em_layout.'

Comment: @X'Factor don't know the reason but after removing vc__em_layout from xml it is working fine.:)

Comment: Problem is because of that applied a different id for include layout which have a already id of error_layout. Thats why.

Answer (score 3):

First write super constructor in `onCreate` method  as mentioned below in your activity      class

```
super.onCreate(arg0); 
setContentView(R.layout.verification_code_layout);
init();
```

Hope so it'll help, And in `xml`

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/vc__em_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
                android:visibility="gone" >

                <include layout="@layout/error_message_layout" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using an `<include>` tag to include a layout, any attributes you specify in the `include` element override those of the included layout's root element.

In your case,

```
<include 
    android:id="@+id/vc__em_layout"
```

overrides the id in

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/error_layout"
```

and the view cannot be found with `R.id.error_layout`.

Answer (score -1):

In java super is used to call parent class constructor , so first you need to call Activity class  constructor by

```
     super.onCreate(Bundle_object);
```

and another thing is that onCreate() is initialize life cycle component so you need to use

```
  super and this
```

both keyword as first line of constructor